# Is it possible to cancel raised flag by me?

Tags: support, flags

Lets say I'm flagging a question for `unclear what you are asking` or for `too broad`, many times this happen with badly written homework question. But after 10-20 minutes the question is edited by the OP and now there is more sense in it.

**How I can cancel my flag in this case ? I can't find anywhere cancel functionality.**

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible. Just hope that is will get declined.

Comment: Okay I look into the other question it looks like you just can't.